# DocumentSnapshot.exists returns false when Document exists

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React Native and Firebase Firestore. Below is my code where the error persists. It should display true, as the document does exist inside of the firestore, however it keeps returning false. I tried testing it with a value that I manually created on the Firestore website and the .exists property was true. When I create a document with .set however, it returns false. Anyone have an explanation or a solution as to why this could be happening? I have referred to other StackOverflow articles but they were not helpful as this does not seem to be happening to anyone else. Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks in advance.

```
export default class GuestSession extends Component {

    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        users: [],
        code: 0
    }

     constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let displayName = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName
        this.state.code = props.route.params.code

         const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('sessions').doc(this.state.code)

         docRef.get().then((docSnapshot) => {
             if(docSnapshot.exists) {
                 console.log("exists")
             } else {
                 console.log("doesn't exist")
             }
         })

        this.state.isLoading = false


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some security rules that would prevent doc creation? Also are you sure that `this.state.code` has a value different than the default 0 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my issue. When dynamically creating documents on the go, you want to make sure that you are creating a single document first, instead of a document that includes a collection with another document. For example,

```
//dynamic document creation of 2 separate documents
firebase.firestore().collection('sessions').doc(this.state.code)
.collection('users').doc('exampleUserDocument').set({username: username})
```

should instead be written as

```
const sessionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('sessions')
sessionRef.doc(this.state.code).set({exampleField: value}) 
//properly sets session document

sessionRef.doc(this.state.code).collection('users').doc('exampleUserDocument').set({username: username})
//properly sets user document
```

This allows for the document to be properly created, with all property values of a document to be set for both a session document, and for a user document. I feel like when you do the longer version stated first, it skips over properly creating a document and setting proper values in the session collection to save some loading time for the system. This is more of a hypothesis on what happens rather than a factual statement, but that is my assumption. I hope this helps others in the future.